# Getting the date difference per Product and ID

Tags: sql, ssms

I have a table like this:

[image]

I want to get the date difference between products according to the `Product_Order`, taking into consideration the `ID`. Therefore, the last number of `Product_Order` for a given ID should be NULL.

For example, for `ID` 1 I would like to get the date difference like this:

```
Date Difference
From 1 to 2 - 4 years
From 2 to 3 - 5 years
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window function `LEAD()` to get the next `date` value for the same `id` (ordered by `product_number`), and `DATEDIFF()` to compute the difference:

```
SELECT
    t.*,
    DATEDIFF(
        year,
        LEAD([date]) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY product_order),
        [date]
    ) diff
FROM mytable
```

This will give you the difference in years, which seems to be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the name of the table is 'test'.
Try -

```
select a.date - b.date
from test a, test b
where a.id = b.id 
and a.product_order < b.product_order
```